# wamp for multiple domains

Tags: apache, wampserver

Please can you assist I would like to set up multiple domains on wamp. I have made the following changes.

In C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\httpd.conf

```
Listen 9191
NameVirtualHost *:9191

<VirtualHost *:9191>
    ServerName drop.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/GITpBU/drop/final"
    <Directory "C:/GITpBU/drop/final"> 
       AllowOverride All
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow From all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 9292
NameVirtualHost *:9292

<VirtualHost *:9292>
   ServerName bless.local
   DocumentRoot "C:/GITpBU/bless/website/public_html"
   <Directory "C:/GITpBU/bless/website/public_html"> 
       AllowOverride All
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow From all
   </Directory>
```

In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 drop.local
127.0.0.1 bless.local
```

I have opened the ports for incoming and outgoing connections.

When I type drop.local:9191 in Chrome I receive the error permission is denied for access to this part of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add several ports to listen for your different domains. You can have same port 80 for all your web sites (All domains). For this you need to create virtual hosts in your wamp server. Follow the steps in this url carefuly.
http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Comment: Thanks changed to port 80, the issue was my DocumentRoot "c:\GITpBU\drop\final"
 <Directory  c:/GITpBU/dropshintReloaded/final/> in the httpd vhosts conf file. The quotes and the slashes were the wrong way